# lastupdated contact address store in asscociated account address using trigger

Tags: trigger, controller

---

> Showing ERROR :  but showing Compile Error: Invalid foreign key
>   relationship: Account.contacts

---

when user create contact with assocate there parent account and insert mailing address in contact lastupdated record of address(from contact), store in particular account billing address.
this is trigger

```
trigger copyAddress on Contact (after update , after insert , after delete , after undelete) {
Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
        for ( Contact  con : Trigger.new) {        
            if(con.AccountId != null){
                Ids.add(con.AccountId);
            }
         }
     }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
          for ( Contact  con : Trigger.new) {

             if(con.AccountId != Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId ){
                 if(con.AccountId!=null )
                     Ids.add(con.AccountId);
                 if(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != null)
                 Ids.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);

             }

       }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for (Contact  con : Trigger.old){
            if(con.AccountId != null){
                Ids.add(con.AccountId);
            }
        }   
    }

    if(Ids.size()>0){
        CountTriggerHandler.perform(Ids);
   }
}
```

this is handler class

```
public class CountTriggerHandler {
    public static void perform(set<id> ids){
        list<ACCOUNT> accUpdate = new list<ACCOUNT>([SELECT id ,name , BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState,BillingCountry,(SELECT Id,name ,MailingStreet ,MailingCity,MailingState, MailingCountry  FROM Contacts) FROM ACCOUNT WHERE lastmodifiedbyId IN : ids ]);
       for(Account acc : accUpdate) {
           acc.BillingStreet = acc.contacts.MailingStreet;
           acc.BillingCity= acc.contacts.MailingCity;
           acc.BillingState = acc.contacts.MailingState;
           acc.BillingCountryt = acc.contacts.MailingCountry;

       }
        update accUpdate; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your trigger you are trying to update the address in account from contact. So first of all the below SOQL query may fetch many contacts since a account can have multiple contacts.

```
list accUpdate = new list([SELECT id ,name , BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState,BillingCountry,(SELECT Id,name ,MailingStreet ,MailingCity,MailingState, MailingCountry FROM Contacts) FROM ACCOUNT WHERE lastmodifiedbyId IN : ids ]);
```

So how will the code understand that which contact id it should consider ? You need to provide some kind of criteria to let the code understand which contact record it should pick.

Also you cannot directly assign the contact address value from your account list. This is why you are receiving the error. You will need to create the separate list of contacts and get the address details via SOQL.

One more thing is that nowhere in your trigger code you have called your controller class. The class name is different in controller with the one in trigger. Only the method name is the same.